# Simple bash + sed s command to join six lines

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Given the following file:

temp.txt

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
```

And the following bash/sed commands:

```
for (( i=0; i<6; i++ ))
do
sed "N;1s/\\(.\*\\)\n\\(.\*\\)/\1 \2/" temp.txt
done
```

doesn't produce the desired stout:

```
line1 line2 line3 line4 line5 line6
line7
```

Thanks in advance for any insight you can provide.

Comment: Just 'sed 'N;s/\n/ /` is enough to combine every other line, but remember `sed` does not modify the file in place.  It outputs the result to stdout.  You'd need `sed ... temp.txt > t.txt` / `mv t.txt temp.txt`.

Comment: How many lines temp.txt can have? How line8, line9 etc should be printed if exists? With only 7 lines you can `xargs -L6 -a temp.txt`

Comment: please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and update your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is:

```
for (( i=0; i<6; i++ ))
do
sed "N;1s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\1 \2/" temp.txt
done
```

- `N` tells sed to read the next line. By doing so the current line number is incremented. So testing for line 1 can never succeed. (You should test for line 2.)
- You have not used `-i` and so the file will not be changed.
- It is rather inefficient to call sed 6 times instead of just doing everything in a single invocation. (And you should only call it 5 times to join 6 lines.)

A simpler alternative:

```
sed -i '1{N;N;N;N;N;s/\n/ /g;}' temp.txt
```

---

In the case that the input could have fewer than 6 lines and **up to** 6 lines should be joined, an alternative script is:

```
sed -i ':a;$q;N;1,6s/\n/ /;ta' temp.txt
```

Note that BSD-ish sed requires a literal newline after any label.

Behaviour of `N` when there is no next line varies between implementations. Some output the existing contents of the pattern space, others follow [posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) and discard it. (GNU sed will do either: `seq 3 | sed N` vs `seq 3 | sed --posix N`.) Prefixing `$q` sidesteps this ambiguity and forces output.

Comment: While experimenting with things like this, I recommend having `sed` make a backup of the original file, by using something like `-i.bak` instead of just `-i`.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```bash
$ sed -n -e '1h; 2,6H; 6{g; s/\n/ /g}; 6,$p' temp.txt
line1 line2 line3 line4 line5 line6
line7
```

The first 6 lines get added to the *hold space*, then on the 6th line, the hold space is moved into the *pattern space*, and newlines are replaced with spaces. The 6th and following lines are printed out (The `-n` option turns off printing by default).

(Might be GNU sed specific because of the `\n` in the regular expression, but since this is tagged linux I assume that's the version you're using)

---

You can also use `ed` instead, which has an actual **j**oin command:

```bash
$ printf '%s\n' '1,5s/$/ /' 1,6j ,p Q | ed -s temp.txt                         
line1 line2 line3 line4 line5 line6
line7
```

Add a space to the end of the first 5 lines, join the first 6 lines, and print out the changed file. If you wanted to modify the file directly, just change `,p Q` to `w` to **w**rite it out to disk.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v max=6 '{printf("%s%s", $0, (NR<max ? " " : "\n"))}' file
line1 line2 line3 line4 line5 line6
line7
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;s/\n/&/5;Ta;s// /g' file
```

Or if you prefer:

```
sed ':a;N;s/[^\n]*/&/6;Ta;s/\n/ /g' file
```

Or with paste:

```
paste -sd'     \n' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7' |
```

---

```
 mawk '!__ < (_ = NR % 6) || ORS = _ ? OFS : RS' ORS=' '
```

---

```
line1 line2 line3 line4 line5 line6
line7
```

another way to be a tiny bit more efficient (*`124` micro-ops instead of `153`*) :

---

```
gawk 'ORS < FS ? ORS = FS : NR % 6 || ORS = RS' ORS=' '
```